# Why does Star Boy name get changed in DCAU?

Tags: character, dc-animated-universe, justice-league-vs-the-fatal-five

In comics, Star Boy's name is **Thom Kallor** (not **Thomas**) but in *Justice League vs. the Fatal Five*, his name was changed to **Thomas Kallor**. But why was this change done? Is it something to do with Bruce Wayne's father's name which is Thomas Wayne? Or some other reason for the change? As changing name to short form is not so unusual but enlarging name might have some reason behind it.

Comment: Thom <-> Thomas ?

Comment: @Vishwa didn't got your point?

Comment: I think Vishwa's point is that Thom could simply be a shortened version of "Thomas"

Comment: @MBorg in comics his name was clearly Thom, not Thomas.

Comment: @Vishwa it's not a short form, read question again

Comment: @AnkitSharma didn't watch the flick yet, just gave out first thing came in my mind. it's worth looking why is he named Thom originally, since it's not a usual name. Anyway why so many downvotes?

Comment: @Vishwa no idea about the backlash. My most downvoted question till now :D

Comment: @AnkitSharma your worst is 4? :O

Comment: @Vishwa I didn’t initially DV as I gave OP the benefit of the doubt that maybe shortening of names isn’t something common in every culture. However, after OPs stubbornness that the answer he was being given in comments and answers isn’t correct, the I reluctantly DV’d. What’s the point in asking a question if you won’t accept what you’re being told?

Comment: The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thom) page for Thom seems to indicate it's both a short form of Thomas and something of an entirely different origin  at first glance, so both the answerer and the asker would probably be right. There might be some validity to this question, but perhaps only the creators can confirm? @Darren regardless of the validity of the disagreement, I thought it's a good thing that an asker doesn't blindly accept the answer and gives some thought to it.

Comment: @Darren You've provided no actual evidence that Thom is intended to be the shortened form of Thomas, so why *should* they accept your answer?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Fair point. I've updated my answer with a quote from Wikipedia. I could also supply a number of Toms who have Thomas on their birth certificate if required :)

Comment: @Darren That's not relevant evidence. Nobody is disputing that Thom **can be** a shortened form of Thomas. People are disputing that this particular Thom is officially called Thomas. Is there any evidence related to this specific character being asked about where it's made clear that their actual name is Thomas and they're just called Thom as a shortened form?

Comment: Can I suggest this conversation goes to chat before we add too many more comments here?

Comment: @Ankit Sharma  You remind me of some Star Trek fans who claim it is a big deal that Captain Kirk's name is given as "James R. Kirk" once and "James T. Kirk" & "James Tiberius Kirk" other times.  They forget that people can have more than one middle name & initial. A great great great grandmother of mine was named Ann Frances Veronica Hurst and married Jacob Demuth in 1822.  When she was a widow from 1842 to 1868 she was called "Mrs. Demuth", "Widow Demuth", and by varying combinations of her names and initials.  Her full name didn't change, people just used different shorter versions of it.

Comment: @M.A.Golding why repeating same commnet again when we already ahve too many commnets :D

Answer (score -2):

Tom and Thom are shortened forms of Thomas in the same way that Will is a shortened form of William etc. If someone is called Tom/Thom, it is perfectly plausible that their birth certificate will say Thomas (and possibly they might be called that in more formal settings/by their parents etc).

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thom):

> Thom is also a first name variant of the abbreviation "Tom" of "Thomas" that holds the "h".

Comment: His name was Thom not Thomas in comics, there is no short form

Comment: @AnkitSharma yes, I understand. But I feel like you are not listening to what you are being told here and in the comments. Someone can be called Tom, and it is equally valid (usually) to call them Thomas. Liz = Elizabeth, Rob = Robert/Robin and so on.

Comment: Will -< William also Bill <- William and Bob-< Robert and Rob/Robbie

Comment: @Darren however Elizabeth gets shorten to Liz. Robert/Robin shorten to Rob. the practice is generally to shorten the same, not make it longer and from what i keep reading, the name has always been Thom. also consider [Lex Luthor's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_Luthor) name is **Alexander Joseph "Lex" Luthor** while i never see that for [Thom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thom_Kallor)

Comment: @Darren in AnkitSharma's defense, then why didn't they just call the character Thomas to begin with, because even if "Thom" is a shortened version of Thomas, that doesn't seem to be specified anywhere "in the comics" in relation to this character AND Will or Bill is much more common nick name, then "Thom", as most in contemporary society would opt for Tom and omit the "h" all together. I think the question about why the name designation changed is valid, even if does come down to "Thomas". I think it still deserves some "proof".

Comment: @Ankit Sharma  Suppose that  for years a fictional character is called "Billy Dee", and you sometimes read that his family name is Kidd.  Then after years, and after he might have grown up a lot, he is suddenly called "William Donald Kidd".  Wouldn't you naturally assume that his name was always "William Donald Kidd" and he was just called "Billy" because it is short for William, and "Dee" because that's how the initial "D" would be pronounced? Why assume that "Thom Kallor" & "Thomas Kallor" are different from "Billy Dee Kidd" & "William Donald Kidd"?

Comment: @Ankit Sharma  You remind me of some Star Trek fans who claim it is a big deal that Captain Kirk's name is given as "James R. Kirk" once and "James T. Kirk" & "James Tiberius Kirk" other times.  They forget that people can have more than one middle name & initial. A great great great grandmother of mine was named Ann Frances Veronica Hurst and married Jacob Demuth in 1822.  When she was a widow from 1842 to 1868 she was called "Mrs. Demuth", "Widow Demuth", and by varying combinations of her names and initials.  Her full name didn't change, people just used different shorter versions of it.